# Get rails association from foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reflection

What I want: for a given foreign key name, and the model class, I can get the association (to know which model it can be resolved to).

For example:

```
# model: product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

# resolution:
association = Product.get_association('category_id')
```

So I need this `get_association` function.

What I know now:

1. from Product.reflections I can get a list of reflections / associations
2. for one reflection, I can get the foreign key
3. I can build a map for this foreign key, to get the association

However, I want to ask if there is a simple method I can call directly?

Update: What I actually need

I'm implementing an `audit log` view using [audit](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited). However, when I was trying to output the audit log, what I can get is something like this:

```
supplier_id: changed from '1' to '0'
```

I want to replace the numbers with the actual name of the supplier, therefore I believe that if given `supplier_id`, I should be able to get teh `Supplier` model.

Plus, because I used like:

```
belongs_to :reporter, class_name: 'User'
```

I therefore cannot simply guess the class name from the given key.

Comment: Hey, What is your actual need ?, That explanation is little bit confusing. Please elaborate more in details.

Comment: @Bharatsoni Use case updated :)

Comment: @songyy, did you find solution ?

Answer (score 3):

<s>You are looking for [reflect_on_association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_association)</s>

<s>`Product.reflect_on_association(:category)`</s>

**Edit**: Don't use reflect* here.

tl;dr: Log class name and use `.find`

---

If your models look like

```
class Employee
  belongs_to :manager, foreign_key: :manager_id
end

class Manager
  has_many :subordinates, foreign_key: :manager_id, class_name: 'Employee'
end
```

and the logfile says something like: `manager_id: changed from '1' to '2'`, the model which has been changed would be `Employee`, because it has the column `manager_id`. But there is no way to figure that out from the example log in your question, because since more than one model can have the column `manager_id` it's not possible to get a clear answer. But in this simple case we know the associated model is `Manager` and the numbers in the log could be replaced with the name: `Manager.find(1)`, `Manager.find(2)`. No reflection magic needed here.

---

Think this case:

```
class Employee
  belongs_to :manager, foreign_key: :department_id, class_name: 'Manager'
end

class Responsibility
  belongs_to :manager, foreign_key: :organizer_id, class_name: 'Manager'
  belongs_to :department, foreign_key: :department_id, class_name: 'Department'
end

class Manager
  has_many :subordinates, foreign_key: :organizer_id, class_name: 'Employee'
  has_many :obligations, foreign_key: :organizer_id, class_name: 'Responsibility'
end

class Department
  has_many :obligations, foreign_key: :department_id, class_name: 'Responsibility'
end
```

If your log only contains `department_id: changed from '1' to '2'` you can't know what exactly has been changed in your company.

To solve the problem you have to log the class name of the associated model (not of the model that has been changed). If you have the class name you don't need any reflection here, it would be just a `.find` like in the first simple case.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But It seems I can only call `Product.reflect_on_association(:category)`; calling `Product.reflect_on_association(:category_id)` would return me a `nil`

Comment: You are right. Fixed it in the answer.  If you only have the string including the `_id` part, you can use `.sub!(/_id$/, '')` to remove it.

Comment: Hmm but sometimes the foreign might not be `[association_name]_id`, because I can actually set the foreign key like: `has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee",
                          foreign_key: "manager_id"`

Comment: Edited my answer, again.

Comment: thanks :) I actually used your way in my code. And I showed the class name in the form :)

Comment: Do you use `.reflect_on_association` or `.find`? I think you should go with `.find`. I think `.reflect_on_association` could break sooner or later.